# How to know the type of features that the Featuretools generates?

Tags: featuretools

How to know the type of features (numeric, categorial) that [Featuretools](https://featuretools.com) generates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the generated feature definitions, there is a `variable_type` attribute to see the type of feature.

```py
feature_matrix, feature_defs = ft.dfs(target_entity='customers', entityset=es)

feature_defs[1], feature_defs[1].variable_type
```

```
(<Feature: COUNT(sessions)>, featuretools.variable_types.variable.Numeric)
```

Let me know if that helps.